# Get User Auth Profile Info in Firebase using Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

Can you help me? I can't get the user's profile information in Angularfire Authentication like their facebook's profile picture or facebook name. Please help. Thanks a lot!

I've tried this code but its not working. I use Angular 2 TypeScript.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var name, email, photoUrl, uid;

if (user != null) {
  name = user.displayName;
  email = user.email;
  photoUrl = user.photoURL;
  uid = user.uid;  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
                   // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
                   // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
}
```

Comment: there appears to be some code missing?

Comment: That's sa sample code in firebase. I have search it for angular and I found nothing. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using **Angularfire2** this should be the way:

```
constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
     //Here you get the user information
     console.log(auth));
    }
  }
  login() {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup,
    });
  }
```

Take a look here for more information: https://angularfire2.com/api/

Comment: This is the old SDK and the OP is using the new SDK.

Comment: Well done. But this is the Javascript SDK, the OP said he is using AngularFire2

Comment: Thanks! I got it with your sample code. And I did what I want by using authData.auth.displayName to get the specific data in the Object! Really Appreciate it Thanks a lot! @muetzerich

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for angular4? This currently isn't working for me:
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.afAuth.auth.subscribe(

Answer (score 4):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md) in the **Example app** section, you can use `auth.subscribe` to detect the auth state:

```
export class myClass {
  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
        if(auth) {
            console.log('You are authenticated', auth)
        } else {
            console.log('You are not authenticated')
        }

    });
  }
}
```