# Get User Auth Profile Info in Firebase using Angular4 and Angularfire2 (v4)

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

Looking at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309758/get-user-auth-profile-info-in-firebase-using-angular2) (angular2), I have been trying to get the same functionality to work in angular4 and coming up short. The error I get is:

*Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Auth'*

Here is some sample code (not working):

**angularFire.ts (provider):**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { FirebaseObjectFactoryOpts } from "angularfire2/interfaces";
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class AF {
  public messages: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  public users: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  public displayName: string;
  public email: string;
  public user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.afAuth.auth.subscribe(
      (auth) => {
        if (auth != null) {
          this.user = db.list.object('users/' + auth.uid);
        }
      });
    this.messages = db.list('messages');
    this.users = db.list('users');
  } ... 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With AngularFire2 you have to subscribe to `authState`, not `auth`.

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe()
```

Comment: it says it is not assignable to user: Observable<firebase.User>;